# How can I get my orderby to work using an anonymous type?

Tags: linq

What do I put in my order by??  I want to order by Name.  I have moved the orderby after the distinct because I read that it needs to be done last.

```
   var result = (from r in db.RecordDocs
                  where r.RecordID == recordID
                  select new
                             {
                                 DocTypeID = r.Document.DocType.DocTypeID,
                                 Name = r.Document.DocType.Name,
                                 Number = r.Document.DocType.Number
                             }
                 ).Distinct().OrderBy( );
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do

```
.OrderBy(doc => doc.Name)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option, if you really prefer the query expression syntax would be to chain your query construction across multiple statements:

```
var query = from r in db.RecordDocs
    where r.RecordID == recordID
    select new
    {
        DocTypeID = r.Document.DocType.DocTypeID,
        Name = r.Document.DocType.Name,
        Number = r.Document.DocType.Number
    };

query = query.Disctinct();
query = from doc in query orderby doc.Name select doc;
```

Since all of these methods are deferred, this will result in the exact same execution performance.